# PrestaShop Product Import Issues

Tags: prestashop

First of all, I will give you the specifications of the install:

PrestaShop Version: 1.3.6
PHP Version: 5.2.6
MySQL Version: 5.0.51b
Apache Version: 2.2.8

All the above are running on a WAMP install.

Now, the error. I am attempting to import a product catalog of 4,521 products into the install. In order for this to run smoothly, I have split the import into 41 different CSV files. Ranging from 5 products minimum in 1 sheet up to a maximum limit of 150 products per sheet. The import is only importing 7 fields: Category, Name, Price Tax Incl., Image, Custom Feature 1, Custom Feature 2 and Reference #.

The issue arises during the import. A CSV with 30 products imports just fine, but one with 90 products fails at 76 and one with 146 fails at 87. For some reason they are not importing any more and then the backend import screen fails and just shows the header and footer but with a blank tiny content area as if the page didn't fully load!

I find it very strange as the CSV with 146 products previously gave no problem during import but now limits to importing 87 products!

Has anybody every had this occur or something similar, and if so, how did you fix it??

PS: Before anyone asks, I have upped the memory limits in PHP.ini such as: upload_max_filesize; max_input_time; memory_limit; max_execution_time; post_max_size. None of this has worked.

Thanks,
Cian

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like either a timeout error or Out of memory error.

Try to turn on error reporting in /config/config.inc.php line #4) and retry.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have over 17000 existing customer records. I try to import. When I tried whole file I managed to insert around 5000 records. Later I divided original file into smaller files which have 5000 records at most than I could import around 1500 records :) Later I tried file with 1000 records result was even smaller. In the end I tried file with 200 records at most and I could import around 87 using cvsimport. This is meaningless. Everytime I clear the table before cvsimport....